# Using Media Button Broadcasts with Samsung's default media player

Tags: android, android-music-player, android-mediaplayer

I built an app using Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON to control the current media play, but a customer reported it wasn't working with their Samsung music player. Does anyone know if the Samsung media player doesn't support media buttons, and if so how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution for you, but I can confirm that the stock media player on my Samsung Galaxy S / Android 2.1 testing unit does not respond to either 'toggle play/pause' (KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) or 'next track' (KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT), so it's a fair bet that it won't respond to others either.

If you use logcat to follow what happens when you use the stock headset to 'toggle play/pause' using the inline switch/mic, you can see it sending KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK, which you can send in code and will at least 'toggle play/pause' on the stock media player.

But that's it. Bit rubbish, really. Good on ya, Samsung!

EDIT: After a bit more digging I got the following to work with the Samsung Media Player:

```
Intent musicIntent = new Intent();
musicIntent.setAction("com.sec.android.app.music.musicservicecommand.togglepause");
sendBroadcast(musicIntent);
```

and:

```
Intent musicIntent = new Intent();
musicIntent.setAction("com.sec.android.app.music.musicservicecommand.next");
sendBroadcast(musicIntent);
```

I would be very interested to know how generally applicable this is - seems a bit fragile to me...

And lastly, along the same lines I found (replace the musicIntent.setAction() line with):

```
musicIntent.setAction("com.android.music.musicservicecommand.next");
musicIntent.putExtra("command", "next"); // or "next" or "previous"
```

This did not work with the Samsung player, but might be of use to someone...